# Select All from one table and fill values from another table on the result

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want get full column from one table and select sum from another table that have same id.

Eg:

```
 table1          table2 
 id    target        id    target achived
 1      40           1      20
 2      50           2      25
 3      66
 4      80
```

and i want to select all from table 1 and fill achived target results on it.

Eg:

```
 id    target  target achived
  1      40         20
  2      50         25
  3      66          0
  4      80          0


how can i do that using mysql
```

Comment: you can achieve with left join

Comment: And note Santosh's spelling of achieve

Comment: didn't get you @Strawberry

Comment: My comment was addressed to the OP

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
 select table1.*, case when table2.target_achieved is null 
                  then 0
                  else table2.target_achieved
                  end as target_achieved
       from table1 left join table2 
       on table1.id = table2.id 
       order by table1.id
```

Comment: I got it @Strawberry, to write zeros if there is no record on table2,so how should I put this on my query?

Comment: COALESCE(table2.target_achieved,0) -  but see about table aliases too.

Answer (score 0):

Below query results in `0` instead of `NULL`

```
SELECT t1.id, target, COALESCE(target_achieved, 0) AS target_achieved 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: When did COALESCE become so unpopular?